# Name of the incoming parameter same as field name

Tags: c#

```
class  Person
{
  public string name;

  public void SetName(string name)
  {
    name = name;
  }
}    

public void static Main(string[] args)
{    
  Person aPerson = new Person();
  aPerson.SetName("ruby");

  Console.WriteLine("person name is {0}}, aPerson.name);
}
```

The person's name is empty. This can eliminated using `this.name = name;`

What was the reason person name is empty(empty string)?

Comment: How is this not a real question? It's a newbie question, but it's a _real_ newbie question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, your assignment of

```
name = name;
```

is just assigning the value of the parameter *back to itself*. In other words, it's a no-op.

If you change it to:

```
this.name = name;
```

then that's assigning the value of the parameter *to the field* which is what you intended.

However, currently the Person's `name` field *won't* refer to an empty string - it will be a null reference. There's a big difference between the two.

(Of course, normally you shouldn't have a public field, and you should use a property instead of a `SetName` method.)

Comment: @Jon : assinging the paramter back to itself , can u tell how does it happens and how this will create a null reference

Comment: @Raghav55: You're just assigning a value, that's all. Imagine it was an `int` variable: you're saying "let the value of the variable be... the value of the variable". So it does nothing useful.

Comment: @Jon :but why a null reference is set

Comment: @Raghav55: The default value for the field is a null reference. As the original code doesn't assign any *other* value to the field, you've got a null reference.

Comment: @jon: sorry to many questions public void SetName(string name) { name = name } so compilers treat the incoming paramaters as the local variable , but why a compilation error is not given

Comment: @Raghav55: It's perfectly *valid* code. You should get a *warning*, but it isn't an error.

Answer (score 0):

In the method

```
public void SetName(string name) 
{ 
    name = name; 
}
```

you do not set your public field but the parameter. To set the public field you should use

```
public void SetName(string name) 
{ 
    this.name = name; 
}
```

A better approch is to use a Property:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return this.name; }
    set { this.name = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the `this` keyword you are just re-assigning the value of the name parameter to the parameter itself. The `this` keyword gives you the instance to work on.

A better approach might be

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Some people like to use an underscore for private member fields

```
private string _name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the input parameter (name) to itself. By using this.name = name you're explicitly assigning the input parameter (name) to the member variable (this.name). Note that it's quite common to use a naming scheme for member variable to make it easier to distingush them from local variables, e.g. by prefixing them with an underscore or "m_". This, however, varies.

Answer (score 0):

In your SetName method you are setting the variable to the incoming variable which does nothing, when you are using the this. property it will set the name in the class level instead of the incoming parameter

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be easier to see with a slight modification of your code:

```
class  Person
{
  public string name;

  public void SetName(string theName)
  {
    theName = theName;
  }
}
```

Assigning `theName = theName` clearly does not change `name`, which is the data member you intend to set. So you must use:

```
this.name = theName;
```